# ireport excel output containing empty spaces instead of empty columns

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel, subreport

i have added a subreport in the table of the main report to display elements in the same row , but when the subreport turns one line the excel output displays empty rows in the part of the subreport , how can i make it dispaly empty comlums instead of empty spaces.

the excel output :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Vs7.png

the ireport model :
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFcku.png

Answer (score 0):

Put blank text fields behind Subreport same as width of columns in subreport.
Click on send backword
Place subreport above that.

For example in below image. I created blank text fields , selected them and right clicked, clicked "send backward"
Then placed the sub report above these columns. So when subreport is not printed, these blank fields wil get printed.

[image]

Comment: thank you a lot for the answer it worked for me but i have a problem it works  only when one column is in the front and the rest of the columns are in the back , i did my best to corrected it but it didn't work for the excel format it shows an empty space if all the columns are in the back , do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: this is strange, I guess subreport columns and blank columns are not aligned properly. I don't see any other reason. Also check if there is print when condition in band, apply same to blank column, I have created numerous excel report using same. If it doesn't work, Please share jrxml of both main & subreport.